# Complicated array operation

Tags: php, arrays

I have a pretty complicated array operation, or at least it is complicated for me. Lets say I got such kind of array

```
$myArr['url_1']['linktypes']['follow'] = 10;
$myArr['url_1']['linktypes']['nofollow'] = 20;
$myArr['url_1']['linktypes']['other'] = 30;

$myArr['url_2']['linktypes']['follow'] = 40;
$myArr['url_2']['linktypes']['nofollow'] = 50;
$myArr['url_2']['linktypes']['other'] = 60;

$myArr['url_3']['linktypes']['follow'] = 70;
$myArr['url_3']['linktypes']['nofollow'] = 80;
$myArr['url_3']['linktypes']['other'] = 90;
```

and simply (!) I need to get following result

```
array(
    array("id"=>1,"metric"=>'follow','url_1'=>10,'url_2'=>40,'url_3'=>70),
    array("id"=>2,"metric"=>'nofollow','url_1'=>20,'url_2'=>50,'url_3'=>80),
    array("id"=>3,"metric"=>'other','url_1'=>30,'url_2'=>60,'url_3'=>90)
);
```

These array elements are created  dynamicall from $myArr. I have tried many ways but I failed many times. Hopefully someone has a short, simple logic to solve this.

Thanks.
Edit: This one is my shortest try. I have many different ways but this code is a part of big code structure, example you see here is created to simplify the logic I need.

```
$linkStructure = array();
foreach($myArr as $links=>$value){
    $counter = 0;

    foreach($value['linktypes'] as $ltKey => $ltValue){
        if($linkStructure[$counter]["id"] && $linkStructure[$counter]["metric"] == $ltKey){
            $linkStructure[$counter][$links] = $ltValue;
        }
        else{
            $linkStructure[$counter]["id"] = $counter;
            $linkStructure[$counter]["metric"] = $ltKey;
            $linkStructure[$counter][$links] = $ltValue;
        }
    }

}
```

I swear I tried how I can prove better I don't know. Don't torture please. If you have any idea just share, is it too much I'm asking for?

Comment: this isn't really how arrays should work. what happens if there are 4 URLS, how would you check for this?

Comment: Many different kind of foreach loops, array functions but I didn't want to put them here because they were wrong. If needed I can post some but I don't think they will be helpful.

Comment: @ufucuk: Post them even if they are wrong, just show us you tried.

Comment: where is id in your source array?

Comment: If there are 4 or 1000000 urls there is no difference because it is dynamically generated it can go on $myArr['url_4'],$myArr['url_5'] it doesn't matter. And I'm pretty sure this is a good way to use arrays.

Comment: @ufucuk Please edit your question to include your code.

Comment: Post it in your original post, not in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain this very well, so I'm just going to use code:

```
$fixedArr = array();
$idCount = 1;

foreach($myArr as $title=>$subArr)
  foreach($subArr['linktypes'] as $metric=>$val) {
    if(!array_key_exists($metric)) {
      $fixedArr[$metric] = array();
      $fixedArr[$metric]['id'] = $idCount;
      $fixedArr[$metric]['metric'] = $metric;
      $idCount += 1;
    }
    $fixedArr[$metric][$title] = $val;
  }
```

That should do it.

But I should say that the comments are right, a better way to structure your array would be like this:

```
Array {
  [url_*] => Array {
    [metric] => someValue;
  }
}
```

Basically the same way you have it originally, but with fewer dimensions. This is all that you need for the data you have provided.

Comment: did you even try this code to see the result? Well I did for you, first it is buggy, second it doesn't work when you fix the bug.

Comment: Not directly, but I have done a similar operation many times. This is basically the code I use. And it would help to know whats buggy about it.

Comment: The method which uses the result array accepts only this type of structure. If I could control it I would really create a better design.

Comment: Updated. It should follow your structure now, and is infinitely flexible in every dimension.

Comment: array
  'follow' => 
    array
      'id' => int 7
      'metric' => string 'follow' (length=6)
  'nofollow' => 
    array
      'id' => int 8
      'metric' => string 'nofollow' (length=8)
      'url_3' => int 80
  'other' => 
    array
      'id' => int 6
      'metric' => string 'other' (length=5)

Comment: It was just missing a `{` and a `}`. Fixed it.

Comment: With a little more modification it solved my problem. Thanks a lot.